# How to write a brute-force algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, brute-force

I'm currently looking for a bruteforce algorithm and I just can't find a good/simple one.
So I tried to write one myself, but I failed. I'm just too bad at math or whatever. :/
I don't need the algorithm in a specific programming language, if you have one, I can probably port it to the language I need it in.
I'm basically looking for something as simple as this:
(my attempt to write a bruteforce function)

```
function BruteForce(chars,minLen,maxLen)
    curCharArray = {}
    for i=1, maxLen do
      curCharArray[i] = 0
    end
    generatedString = ""
    for currentLength = minLen, maxLen, 1 do
        curCharArray[currentLength] = 1
        Pos=currentLength
        while Pos>0 do

            if string.len(generatedString) < 1 then 
                generatedString= string.sub(chars,curCharArray[Pos],curCharArray[Pos])
            else
                generatedString= string.sub(generatedString,1,Pos-1) .. string.sub(chars,curCharArray[Pos],curCharArray[Pos])
            end

                print(generatedString)

            curCharArray[Pos] = curCharArray[Pos]+1
            Pos = currentLength
            while curCharArray[Pos]==string.len(chars)+1 do
                curCharArray[Pos]=1
                Pos = Pos-1
            end
        end
    end
end

BruteForceAttack("abc",2,3)
```

It's written in Lua, you can run the code online here: http://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo
The output is:

```
a
ab
ac

a
ab
ac
a
aa
ab
ac
b
ba
bb
bc
c
ca
cb
cc
cca
ccb
ccc
ca
caa
cab
cac
cb
cba
cbb
cbc
cc
cca
ccb
ccc
a
aa
aab
aac
aa
aaa
aab
aac
ab
aba
abb
abc
ac
aca
acb
acc
b
ba
bab
bac
ba
baa
bab
bac
bb
bba
bbb
bbc
bc
bca
bcb
bcc
c
ca
cab
cac
ca
caa
cab
cac
cb
cba
cbb
cbc
cc
cca
ccb
ccc
```

As you can see some outputs are the same and the minimum length is not being considered. Also, the order is wrong.
I wanted the output to be:

```
aa
ab
ac
ba
bb
bc
ca
cb
cc
aaa
aab
aac
aba
abb
abc
aca
acb
acc
baa
bab
bac
bba
bbb
bbc
bca
bcb
bcc
caa
cab
cac
cba
cbb
cbc
cca
ccb
ccc
```

Comment: You haven't said what you're brute forcing.

Comment: @pjs I'm just looking for an algorithm that I think is known as "brute-force".

Comment: @Forivin: I think you should clarify that you're bruteforcing all 2-3 letter combinations of "abc" where order is irrelevant.

Comment: @Forivin "Brute Force" is a type of attack, which usually means trying all possibilities, usually with passwords in mind, meaning you start with "A", the, "AA", "AAA", etc. What you actually appear to be after in your example, is a dictionary creating program. You would generate your dictionary, then feed that text file into something like John The Ripper password cracking program.

Comment: Why is the order important?  Usually the order isn't important in brute-force.

Comment: @MooingDuck The function call is in my code, so it should be clear how I'm calling the function.  
@ SnakeDoc Okay, I'm definitely not attacking anything and I'm not looking for a hack or anything and I'm not planning to do anything illegal. I'm just interested in the algorithm that created an ordered list of every possible combination of a given charset...

Comment: I don't understand what you thought your code was doing.  Why not simply recursively generate the strings? http://ideone.com/8HEPAm  Recursion or trivial loops are usually the easiest way to brute force.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't know LUA but I think idea is clear from this JavaScript snippet:

```
function generate(current, len, chars) 
{
    if (current.length == len)
        console.log(current);
    if (current.length < len)
        for (var i in chars) {
            generate(current + chars[i], len, chars) 
        }
}

function brute(chars, min, max)
{
    for (var l = min; l <= max; ++l)
        generate("", l, chars);
}

brute(['a', 'b', 'c'], 2, 3);
```

**UPDATE**: Snippet without recursion:

```
function generateNoRecursion(len, chars) 
{
    // Indices that indicate what char to use on corresponding place.
    var indices = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        indices.push(0);

    // While all indices in set of chars
    while (indices[0] < chars.length)
    {
        // Print current solution
        var str = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < indices.length; ++i)
            str += chars[indices[i]];
        console.log(str);
        // Go to next solution by incrementing last index and adjusting
        // if it is out of chars set.
        indices[len-1]++;
        for (var i = len-1; i > 0 && indices[i] == chars.length; --i)
        {
            indices[i] = 0;
            indices[i-1]++;
        }
    }
}

function brute(chars, min, max)
{
    for (var l = min; l <= max; ++l)
        generateNoRecursion(l, chars);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Many programming languages have such a capability in some standard library. For example, in Python, you could do:

```
import itertools 

def print_perms(chars, minlen, maxlen): 
    for n in range(minlen, maxlen+1): 
        for perm in itertools.product(chars, repeat=n): 
            print(''.join(perm)) 

print_perms("abc", 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks @Dmitry Poroh for good idea. I implemented code on lua:

```
symbols = {'A','B','C'}

lenght = {min = 2, max = 3}

function print_t(t)
    for _,v in pairs(t) do
    io.write(v)
    end
    print()
end

function generate(current, len, chars)
    if #current == len then
    print_t(current)
    return
    end
    if #current < len then
    for c = 1, #chars do
    curr = {}
    for i = 1, #current do
        curr[i] = current[i]
    end
    curr[#curr+1] = chars[c]
    generate(curr, len, chars)
    end
    end
end

function brute(chars, min, max)
    for l = min, max do
    generate({}, l, chars)
    end
end

brute(symbols, lenght.min, lenght.max)
```

Result:

```
AA
AB
AC
BA
BB
BC
CA
CB
CC
AAA
AAB
AAC
ABA
ABB
ABC
ACA
ACB
ACC
BAA
BAB
BAC
BBA
BBB
BBC
BCA
BCB
BCC
CAA
CAB
CAC
CBA
CBB
CBC
CCA
CCB
CCC
```

I hope this code is useful to somebody.

Answer (score 0):

The following is my implementation of the BruteForce Algorithm for Java and Free Pascal.

Java

```
/**
 *
 * @author Nikos Siatras
 * https://github.com/nsiatras
 */
public class BruteForce
{

    private static final char[] fCharList =
    {
        'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'
    };

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 17; i++)
        {
            StartBruteForce(i);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method is called every time a new word is generated
     *
     * @param word is the brute force generated word
     */
    private static void OnBruteForceWordGenerated(String word)
    {
        System.out.println(word);
    }

    /**
     * Start a new Brute Force
     *
     * @param length is the words length (how many characters a word can have)
     */
    private static void StartBruteForce(int length)
    {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(length);
        char currentChar = fCharList[0];

        for (int i = 1; i <= length; i++)
        {
            sb.append(currentChar);
        }

        ChangeCharacters(0, sb, length);
    }

    private static StringBuffer ChangeCharacters(int pos, StringBuffer sb, int length)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= fCharList.length - 1; i++)
        {
            sb.setCharAt(pos, fCharList[i]);
            if (pos == length - 1)
            {
                // Write the Brute Force generated word.
                OnBruteForceWordGenerated(sb.toString());
            }
            else
            {
                ChangeCharacters(pos + 1, sb, length);
            }
        }

        return sb;
    }
}
```

FreePascal

```
program Pascal_BruteForce;

(*
  Brute Force Algorithm for FreePascal

  Author: Nikos Siatras
  https://github.com/nsiatras
*)

uses
  SysUtils;

// Global Variables
var
  fCharactersStr: string;
  fCharList: TStringArray;
  fCharactersListLength: integer;

{*
  The OnBruteForceWordGenerated procedure is called everytime a new word
  is generated from the BruteForce algorithm
  For this example I choose only to write to word on the screen
*}
  procedure OnBruteForceWordGenerated(word: string);

  begin
    WriteLn(word);
  end;

(*
  Change characters to each other and generate BruteForce words :)
*)
  procedure ChangeCharacter(pos: integer; sb: array of string; wordLength: integer);
  var
    i, x: integer;
    generatedWord: string;
  begin

    for i := 0 to fCharactersListLength - 1 do
    begin

      sb[pos] := fCharList[i];

      if pos = wordLength - 1 then
      begin
        // Pass the BruteForce generated word to the OnBruteForceWordGenerated
        // procedure
        generatedWord := string.Join('', sb);
        OnBruteForceWordGenerated(generatedWord);
      end

      else
      begin
        ChangeCharacter(pos + 1, sb, wordLength);
      end;

    end;

  end;

(*
  Start Brute Force Generation
  @wordLength is the word's length (how many characters a word can have)
*)
  procedure StartBruteForce(wordLength: integer);
  var
    stringBuilder: array of string;
    currentChar: string;
    i: integer;
  begin

    SetLength(stringBuilder, wordLength);
    currentChar := fCharList[0];

    for i := 1 to wordLength do
    begin
      stringBuilder[i - 1] := currentChar;
    end;

    ChangeCharacter(0, stringBuilder, wordLength);

  end;


  // Main Program
var
  i: integer;

begin

  //Initialize fCharList array
  //For this example I will use all lowercase english alphabet characters.
  fCharactersStr := 'a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z';
  fCharList := fCharactersStr.split(',');

  //Find the length of the fCharList array
  fCharactersListLength := Length(fCharList);

  // Generate all words with total length from 1 to 16 characters
  // This will generate all words from 'a' to 'zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz'
  for i := 1 to 16 do
  begin
    StartBruteForce(i);
  end;

end.
```

Answer (score -1):

When solving a problem, there are different approaches, such as:

- Brute-Force: Try all possible combinations of the state, to get to the solution, through combination enumeration.
- Divide & Conquer: when a problem state is difficult at some point, you divide it into 2 or more identical parts that are solved separately, then the partial-solutions is then merged.
- Dynamic Programming: when the problem is variant on 2 or more dimensions, you rebuild the same problem up to input-size, at each build, you solve the problem linearly by using the optimal solution you got at the size below it.
- Greedy: At each state, if it's not the solution, step to the best neighbor state, which is basically optimization (maximization\minimization) over the cost `g(state)` function.
- Heuristic: At each state, you have the `h(state)` function, which works like an 8-ball, telling you how close a neighbor state is to the solution state.
- .. etc

**Eaxmple:** Search problem.

```
-- Brute Force example, search array

local array = { "apple", "orange", "pear", "banana" }

for i = 1, #array do

  if array[i] == "banana" then

    -- item found

  end

end
```